# ajax not sending json data to webmethod

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am doing simple save operation (Code is as per tutorial)
...but ajax is not sending json data to save method

on Firebug console it displays following Error:

> "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/WebApplication2/WebForm1.aspx/saveData"

(**Note:** My libraries are updated and properly placed.)

ajax

```
    var name = "neeraj";
    var gender = "male";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/saveData",
        data: { 'name': JSON.stringify(name), 'Gender': JSON.stringify(gender) },
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: "true",
        success: function (response) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
```

My page url is

```
  ../WebApplication2/WebForm1.aspx
```

save method(webform1.aspx.cs)

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static int saveData(string name, string Gender) 
{ return 1;}
```

Similar Posts:

- [Returning Response in jquery ajax function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611271/returning-response-in-jquery-ajax-function)
  it suggest to use datatype:"JSON" instead of "jsondata" ...I already have
- [ajax jquery post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555181/ajax-jquery-post-method)
  it suggests to created a seperate webservice for save method in stead of cs file
- [AJAX to web method not returning JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423406/ajax-to-web-method-not-returning-json)
  it suggest to put
  `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`
  on WebMethod .. I already did
- [Send JSON with Ajax to ASP.NET Web Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751693/send-json-with-ajax-to-asp-net-web-method?rq=1)
  it suggest to use JSON.stringify ... this is also not working

Answer (score 1):

finally it is Redirecting .. i was too close ...

instead of

```
data: { 'name': JSON.stringify(name), 'Gender': JSON.stringify(gender) },
```

Just need to change to

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 'name': name, 'Gender': gender }),
```

this post helped

[jQuery AJAX call to an ASP.NET WebMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770679/jquery-ajax-call-to-an-asp-net-webmethod?rq=1)